# React slick fade effect porblem

Tags: reactjs, slick.js, slide, react-slick, react-slideshow-image

my React website from right to left

```
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
```

and I have react-slide to show 1 image every slide

```
const settings = {
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  autoplaySpeed:1500,
  speed: 1000,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  arrows: false,
  initialSlide: 0,
  fade: true,
  rtl: true
};
```

my problem is fade effect not show any image !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no problems in the html or css code, try either of the following cssEase options.

```
cssEase: 'linear',
cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045)'
```

Comment: There is no problem in HTML & CSS and when i make `<html lang="en">`
the slide and the fade effect work normally